# Special linear group contains commutator subgroup of general linear group.

Tags: group-theory

I know that if $F$ field then $\det:GL_n(F)\to F^*$ with $F*$ (multiplicative group) non zero elements of $F$, $\det$ is a homomorphism with $\ker(\det)=SL_n(F)$.

Why commutator of $GL_n(F)$ is contained in $SL_n(F)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the quotient is abelian.  By the first isomorphism theorem, the quotient is isomorphic to a subgroup of $\Bbb F^*$.

$G/H$ is abelian if and only if $H\supset [G,G]$.

Comment: I see. Then $F^*$ is abelian?

Comment: Yes.  Fields are commutative rings.

Answer (score 2):

$\operatorname{det}:\operatorname{GL}_n(F) \rightarrow F^*$. So, if the kernel of this is $\operatorname{SL}_n(F)$, what is the quotient by this kernel a subgroup of? What does it say about the commutator of $\operatorname{GL}_n(F)$ if that quotient is abelian?

Answer (score 2):

The determinant for a commutator is $\det(ABA^{-1}B^{-1})=1$, then 
$ABA^{-1}B^{-1}\in SL_n(F)$.

Answer (score 1):

If $H$ is a subgroup, such that $G/H$ is abelian, $[G,G]$, the commutator subgroups, is contained in $H$. In the context of this problem, $GL_n(F)/SL_n(F) \cong F*$,which is abelian(it is the units of the field). The conclusion follows.