# $[GL_2(F),GL_2(F)]= SL_2(F)$ with $F$ field.

Tags: group-theory

Let $F$ a field. I want proves that $[GL_2(F),GL_2(F)]=SL_2(F)$.
The inclusion $[GL_2(F),GL_2(F)]\subset SL_2(F)$ holds, by ([Special linear group contains commutator subgroup of general linear group.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3657467/special-linear-group-contains-commutator-subgroup-of-general-linear-group/3657473?noredirect=1#comment7516465_3657473))

$SL_2(F)\subset [GL_2(F),GL_2(F)]=SL_2(F)$?
I need for any $A=\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix}$ exists $B,C\in GL_2(F)$ such that $A=BCB^{-1}C^{-1}$ but I can't find $B,C$.

**Actualization 1.**

Let $0,1\in F$.

LEt $\begin{bmatrix}
a & b\\ c & d
\end{bmatrix}\in SL_2(F)$ then $ad-bc=1$.

for all $x\in F$, we have
$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & x\\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
1+1  & 0\\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
1 & x\\ 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
1+1 & 0\\ 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}
1 & x \\ 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}^{-1}$$
where  $$\begin{bmatrix}
1+1 & 0\\ 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}
(1+1)^{-1} & 0 \\ 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}\text{ y  }\begin{bmatrix}
1 & x\\ 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -x\\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$
where $(1+1)^{-1}$ inverse multiplicative of $1+1$ y $-x$ aditive inverse of $x$.

therefore, $\begin{bmatrix}
1 & x\\ 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$ is a product of commutators. Analogously, $\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0\\ x & 1
\end{bmatrix}$ is product of commutators.

Simillary
$$\begin{bmatrix}
x & 0\\ 0 & x^{-1}
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
x & 0\\ 0 &1
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1\\  1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
x & 0\\ 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1\\ 1 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}^{-1}.$$

If $a\neq 0$, we have
$$\begin{bmatrix}
a & b\\ c & d
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0\\ ca^{-1} & 1
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
1 & ab\\ 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
a & 0\\ 0 & a^{-1}
\end{bmatrix}$$
where each matrix is a product of commutators.

If $a=0$  then $b\neq 0$, so
$$\begin{bmatrix}
0 & b\\ c & d
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1\\ -1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -db^{-1}\\ 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
b^{-1} & 0\\ 0 & b
\end{bmatrix}$$
where each matrix is a product of commutators.

And  $\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1\\ -1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$ is a product of commutator, indeed

$$\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1\\ -1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1+1\\ 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 0\\ 1 & 1+1
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1+1\\ 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 0\\ 1 & 1+1
\end{bmatrix}^{-1}$$
therefore $SL_2(F)\subset [GL_2(F),GL_2(F)]$.

This is correct? This idea is by José Carlos Santos 
[Commutator Group of $GL_2(R)$ is $SL_2(R)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2762210/commutator-group-of-gl-2r-is-sl-2r)

Comment: usually commutator is written with a comma, not a colon

Comment: If the result is true (maybe not over all fields though, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_linear_group), it is maybe easier to obtain existence of $B, C$ by a dimensional argument.

Comment: This is not true when $|F|=2$. It is true otherwise.

Comment: with |F|=2 exists a counterexample? o.o

Comment: When $|F|=2$, we have ${\rm GL}(2,F) = {\rm SL}(2,F) \cong S_3$, but $[{\rm GL}(2,F) ,{\rm GL}(2,F) ]$ is a proper subgroup of order $3$.

Comment: I see. $GL_2(F)=SL_2(F)$ because $ad-bc\neq 0$ impllies $ad-bc=1$ (in $F$)
Now,  $SL_2(F)$ have 6 elements and $SL_2(F)$ is not  abelian then $SL_2(F)\simeq S_3$ But, how prove that $[GL_2(F),GL_2(F)]$ has order 3.

Comment: I see, $[S_3,S_3]=A_3$ order 3 then by isomorphism $[GL_2(F),GL_2(F)]$ order 3.